# Directory API missing "Websites[]" Object for a user

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I was trying to find a way to update the links/websites of a User Profile but have struggled to find how to achieve this.

It seem the documentation has reference to it. But nothing shows in a GET request for a User. You cant seem to set this during an Update to a user either.

[Link to reference of Object:](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource)

Am I missing something or does this no longer exist and the documentation needs amending?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. How do you find / set those websites manually from the Admin console?

Comment: Apparently you dont. Its only via the Directory API
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6191788?hl=en